# can I access the unique client Id through GA API?

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am currently querying my Google Analytics data using the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) via R.

I would like to query based on the unique [client ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) as my primary dimension, but I can't find this dimension using the API.

Is it possible to query Google analytics from the API using the client Id as a dimensions?

Answer (score 10):

Update: Client ID is now available in Google Analytics Core Reporting api as ga:clientId.

I've added it in my script and works seamlessly.

Query explorer doesn't support it yet, hopefully soon...

Comment: This is the most correct answer right now.  Great find.

Comment: Is there a way to get a timestamp, event or hit id or some hit order number or so to identify individual events or pageviews?

Answer (score 2):

The only dimensions and metrics that you can use with the Google Analytics API can be found in the [Dimensions and metrics explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) you could also check the metadata API.

As you can see client id is not a valid dimension exposed via the Google Analytics API.   You could set this in a custom dimension  yourself however for it to work your going to have to make sure that its set on every single request you send to Google Analytics.

then you can use the [custom dimension metadata](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns)

## update

As of late 2018 early 2019 it is now possible to query ga:clientid from the google analytics api.

Comment: It looks like the dimension and metrics explorer does not include the `ga:clientId` dimension. I've tested that the `ga:clientId` does work with their APIs

Comment: @MattLavin I'm trying to warehouse as much data as possible using the ClientId as a key from GA. Do you have any idea what might be the best way to do this, presuming that most metrics would provide some risk of aggregation? Apologies if my question is vague.

Comment: I used date as well for aggregation as well as a custom dimension for our internal user id..