# Retrieving user_pseudo_id from GA4 api

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

Is there a way to retrieve the user_pseudo_id field from GA4 api? It is not present in the dimensions list of the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema) but neither was the clientId for UA although it could be specified as a dimension.
See [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623278/can-i-access-the-unique-client-id-through-ga-api) for clientID parameter in the older GA-UA APIs.

I need to retrieve historical data from GA4 and import them into Google BigQuery but not all export's fields are present in the GA4 api.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to pass it as a custom user parameter via Google Tag Manager. Just need to set it once and then the rest of your GA4 tags will inherit it. Here’s a pretty good tutorial on how to do this: https://www.simoahava.com/gtmtips/write-client-id-other-gtag-fields-datalayer/

Comment: This is not retroactive thou. I'm now correctly retrieving data with the BigQuery connector, what I need is to retrieve historical data happened before the BQ connection.